# Issues loading css on specific page in django

Tags: python, django

I don't seem to be getting the css for a specific page to load on django.

This is the code for the page in question

```
#home2.html
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="st-layout ls-top-navbar-large ls-bottom-footer show-sidebar sidebar-l3" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title>Learning</title>
  <link href="{% static 'second/css/vendor/all.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{% static 'second/css/app/app.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"> </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
...
```

This is the structure of the files:
django-project
-->project

> static
>   css
>   img
>   vendor
>   second
>   css
>   images
>   js
>   app
>   templates
>   classroom
>   chool
>   templates
>   mentor
>             home2.html
>   registration
>              login
>              signup

Not sure what I am doing wrong since I am loading the static folder with the css files.

**UPDATE**

Here is my log when I try and open the home2.html page:

```
[02/Jan/2020 13:37:56] "GET /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4099
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:13] "GET /accounts/signup/teacher/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4433
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:24] "POST /accounts/signup/teacher/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4572
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:30] "POST /accounts/signup/teacher/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4667
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "POST /accounts/signup/teacher/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37454
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/50/guy-2.jpg
Not Found: /teachers/css/app/app.css
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/50/guy-2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3028
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/50/guy-6.jpg
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/css/app/app.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2995
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/50/woman-3.jpg
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/50/guy-6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3028
Not Found: /teachers/css/vendor/all.css
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/50/woman-6.jpg
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/50/woman-3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3034
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/110/guy-5.jpg
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/css/vendor/all.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3004
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/110/guy-4.jpg
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/50/woman-6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3034
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/110/guy-3.jpg
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/110/guy-4.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3031
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/110/guy-5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3031
Not Found: /teachers/js/vendor/all.js
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/110/guy-3.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3031
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/js/vendor/all.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2998
Not Found: /teachers/js/app/app.js
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/js/app/app.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2989
Not Found: /teachers/images/people/110/guy-6.jpg
[02/Jan/2020 13:38:39] "GET /teachers/images/people/110/guy-6.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 3031
```

Comment: Your code looks allright. Can you access other static files (eg. images)? 
If you can, then I think your browser cached old css file. Try to open same page in different browser or clear internet browser's cache.

Comment: @RenatoMaretić I can't access the images either